# Where are stream definitions in WSO2CEP 3.0.0 stored?

Tags: wso2

I could not find where the description of the streams defined via UI are stored? Are they stored on h2 database or in an xml file? If the answer is file, where this file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream definitions are stored in the embedded registry of the CEP server. You can access this via the registry UI. But it is not recommended to edit registry definitions in this manner.

If you want certain stream definitions to be available at the time of starting the server, you can define them in the XML file /repository/conf/stream-manager-config.xml. However, please note that this file will be read only at server startup and there is no hot deployable feature available for stream definitions currently. You can refer to the following link [1] for more information.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Working+with+Event+Streams